# menu item in drupal

Tags: drupal-6

I am working in drupal 6 And I want that in particaular menu it show only 3 item whenever new item is added earliest must be disable.And it show only latest 3 item like in news only it show only latest news and last one is removed.note: It does not apply on all menu.
please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to show a list of 3 of the latest news items. Menus will not do this for you, you should use the Views module and create a node view.